Expo SDK upgrade causes Invariant Violation on SDK 50
Recently I have upgraded the old expo SDK 46 to expo SDK 50 with Metro and the web app is working quite well. but when I build the iOS it has a runtime error. the app is not even started when I check the inbuilt debugger. I can see the below error. but couldn't figure out what caused this. when I was searching regarding this issue I came across this git hub issue there is not much in it.
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTLog.logIfNoNativeHook(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTLog.logIfNoNativeHook(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method HMRClient.setup(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 2 and callID 1 for module <unknown>. Args: '[{"app_state":"active"}]', js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes


The most likely culprit is an incorrect path to your app's main JavaScript file (index.js or similar). Ensure this path is configured correctly in your AppDelegate.m file.
